# What is probability that one normal random variable is max of three normal random variables?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have three independent random variables, $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$, and each random variable has different mean. (And I assume they have the same variance).
I would like to know how I can get the probability that $X_1$ is the max of all three.
And help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the distributions?

Comment: I assume they all have the normal distributions with same variance but different means.

Comment: Do values of X1 correspond to values of X2 & X3?

Comment: gung, I don't understand your question. Could you clarify?

Comment: Closely related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87241 (generic formulation), http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173064 (two independent normals), http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139072 (two correlated normals), *etc.*  Note that $X_2-X_1$ and $X_3-X_1$ are correlated Normals and $X_1$ is the max of all $X_i$ if and only if the larger of these two differences is non-positive. Thus, you may directly apply the answer in the last link.

Answer (score 1):

Assume their means are $\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3$, with the same standard deviation, $\sigma$. Then the probability that the first random variable is the max is:

$$P(X_1>X_2,X_1>X_3)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x>X_2|X_1=x)P(x>X_3|X_1=x)f(x)dx$$

where $f(x)$ is the density of $X_1$. It's doubtful whether you can simply this further.

Comment: Since the variables are independent this simplifies to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {P(X_2 < x) P(X_3 < x) f(x) dx}$